# Rails: How to test if an attribute of a class object is required in the model policy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Briefly, I have a model User with name, email and comment as attributes.

```
validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :email
```

So 'name' and 'email' are required but not 'comment'.

```
my_user = User.new
```

I'd like to find a way to test like my_user.name.required? or User.name.required? kind of thing.

My goal is to create a form and to add a specific class dynamically to the form item span or td depending on if this item is set as "validates_presence_of"

I tried to search for it but did not find anything about. Is there a easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There isn't a single method you can call to handle this, but [this post](http://www.keenertech.com/articles/2011/06/26/recipe-detecting-required-fields-in-rails) talks about creating a helper method do to what it sounds like you're after.

```
module InputHelper 
  def required?(obj, attribute)
    target = (obj.class == Class) ? obj : obj.class
    target.validators_on(attribute)
          .map(&:class)
          .include?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator)
  end
end
```

Comment: Two changes to the code snippet above :  
  1. attr in argument should read 'attribute'  
  2. I also had to change ActiveModel to ActiveRecord

Answer (score 6):

Check out this [Railscast about form builder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/311-form-builders?view=asciicast) at 2/3 of the cast :

**/app/form_builders_labelled_form_builder.rb**

```
def field_label(name, *args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  required = object.class.validators_on(name).any? { |v| v.kind_of? ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator }
  label(name, options[:label], class: ("required" if required))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment as I don't have 50 rep, but on Rails 5+ this doesn't work anymore. You can do:

```
ModelName.validators_on(:attribute).any? { |v| v.class == ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator }
```

Answer (score -4):

well if your using rails 3 or above you could do

`validates :name, :presence => true`

and why would you want to add the class dynamically?
You control what attributes need to be filled so on the view form, just add a class on the items tag for the ones that are required.

Comment: The post linked in the previous comment explains why I want to add a class or anything dynamically based on this. Thanks anyway.